# From Bitmaps to Video Streaming

Tags: c#, video, streaming, bitmap, vlc

I'm building a C# application that continuously takes screenshots of the screen. While I'm taking the screenshots, I want to stream them using vlc.
Any ideas of how can I send the bitmaps to vlc for streaming?

tks in advance
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do that, because the bandwith usage will be huge, vlc can't stream bitmap, and vlc can't decode streams of bitmap.

You can consider several solutions :

Jpeg compressing your snapshot, and do the streaming with VLC. From what I understand, VLC can only stream something it can read, a file or another stream, so you will need to stream your jpeg to VLC before VLC can stream them.

Jpeg compressing your snapshot, and doing the streaming yourself. It might be easier than it sounds. Streaming a continous stream of jpeg via http is a very crude protocol so it is quite easy to implement

Give up  reinventing the wheel and use some [vnc](http://www.uvnc.com/) program.